# Leaving inputAccessoryView visible after keyboard is dismissed iOS8?

Tags: ios8, uikeyboard, inputaccessoryview

I want to make behavior like messaging app. I have been browsing Stack Overflow for solutions for this, and indeed there are plenty:

[Leaving inputAccessoryView visible after keyboard is dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768659/leaving-inputaccessoryview-visible-after-keyboard-is-dismissed)

This was the one that I found. But it seems things are a little different in `iOS8`. If I do the same thing in new `iOS8 sdk`, i get error:

```
'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x7fdcb3441b10> should have parent view controller:<ViewController: 0x7fdcb3b1e9f0> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x7fdcb684c000>'
```

In order to test this more I made a sample project, just one controller with view on the bottom:

[image: ViewController code]

[image: Storyboard]

Outlet is connected to bottom view, that only has `UITextField` on it. Am I missing something and how do i get the desired behvior?

Comment: Have you tried it initializing the UIView in code, and making a strong reference to it?

Comment: Yes, the result is the same

Comment: Very weird. Ok, last question – which Xcode version are you using? Including build numbers and everything?

Comment: Did you try my answer? If it worked, accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS8 has a retain cycle with the inputAccessoryView. Here's a good post that seems to have a good workaround:

http://derpturkey.com/uitextfield-docked-like-ios-messenger/

Comment: The one big problem with using that workaround, which implements the inputAccessoryView on the view instead of the view controller is that the animation of the accessory view is not coordinated with the view when pushing the view controller on a navigation stack. Instead of being animated with the view controller's view and sliding with it, the accessory view animates up from the bottom while the view controller view slides in from the right.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the `someView` to multiple superViews, which leads to inconsistent hierarchies (which it is telling you).

When the keyboard gets activated, it calls the `inputAccessoryView()` method to see if it needs to stick anything on top of the keyboard, and adds that to its own superView. But you already added it to the view through your storyboard.

Now there are 2 ways you can solve this:

1. Make a `.xib` with your view and return that one in your `inputAccessoryView()`, not adding it to any superview yourself (the keyboard will.
2. Or make it completely in code using `NSLayoutConstraint`.

You can add the following code to your ViewController which will persist the view even when the keyboard is hidden.

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Look at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/datwelk/RDRStickyKeyboardView) for an example.