# Swift: inputAccessoryView show blank white screen for UIToolbar when called

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, message, inputaccessoryview

I'm trying to add `UIToolbar` to my keyboard with `inputAccessoryView`, but once the user tap the `UITextField` I get an Blank white screen or load White view if i put it in `viewDidLoad()`. I have tried few stackoverflow QA and non of them seems to be working for me. I'm also doing this with `removeFromSuperview()` method.

**Initialization:**

```
@IBOutlet var MessegeView: UIToolbar!
@IBOutlet var MessegeTextField: UITextField!
```

**Assign** `UIToolbar` to `UITextField`: This code result in blank white view when it get loaded.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     MessegeTextField.inputAccessoryView = MessegeView
     MessegeView.removeFromSuperview()    
}
```

**WITHOUT** `removeFromSuperView()`: I get the following error and that make sense kind of.

```
ERROR: 

should have parent view controller:<APPNAME.ChatViewController:XXXXXXXX> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: XXXXXXXXXX>
```

A few Stackoverflow QA I follow (but no result):

- [Error when adding input view to textfield iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029113/error-when-adding-input-view-to-textfield-ios-8)
- [Leaving inputAccessoryView visible after keyboard is dismissed iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496409/leaving-inputaccessoryview-visible-after-keyboard-is-dismissed-ios8)

**How views are setup:** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you setup your UI in a `Storyboard` then you don't own the objects and shouldn't alter the hierarchy. That's why Xcode auto-generated properties from storyboards are `@IBOutlet weak var` by default, you don't own them and shouldn't manage the memory.

To fix your problem you should either use `var MessegeView = UIToolbar()` or you should initialize the toolbar from a separate `.xib`.

Comment: I try the `var MessegeView = UIToolbar()` way, and it didn't work

Comment: Should every single UI be programmatically?

Comment: @NSGod no, all UI shouldn't be programatic, and you don't need the `removeFromSuperview()` if you construct it programatically.

Comment: No luck, I even initialize the toolbar from separate `.xib`