# jsqmessageviewcontroller ios11 toolbar

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, ios11, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have tried the swift example of `JSQMessageViewController` inside iOS 11 simulator. Here is the result:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYraP.png)

I have tried using safe area margin and modify the toolbar constraint but there is still no difference. It seems that the toolbar is outside UIWindow (UITextEffectsWindow instead). Is there any solution?

Comment: Sorry but it's not very clear what you're asking, what are you trying to achieve over all?

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, the keyboard is placed at the bottom of the iphone X stimulator instead of following the safe area guide.

Comment: Likely a bug with JSQ. As you might know, its been deprecated. An effort to replace it is going on over at https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit

Comment: Yes I understand this. But currently the MessageKit has not yet been ready for production. So I am interested if there is any developer solved this problem by themselves

Comment: Anyone has experiences dealing this?

Comment: A topic about this has been opened here: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/2179

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guys I have figured it out! Just put the following code in the JSQMessagesInputToolbar.m. It seems that the inputtoolbar is placed in its own window, you need to access its window separately.

```
-(void) didMoveToWindow{
[super didMoveToWindow];
 if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
     [[self bottomAnchor] constraintLessThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingBelowAnchor:self.window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor multiplier:1.0].active = YES;
     }
}
```

Comment: you must be check about window.safeAreaLayoutGuide not nil coz just use above code app crashes while close the screen so add if condition that can check if nil then skip

Answer (score 10):

Just add an extension for JSQMessagesInputToolbar

```
extension JSQMessagesInputToolbar {
    override open func didMoveToWindow() {
        super.didMoveToWindow()
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *), let window = self.window {
            let anchor = window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
            bottomAnchor.constraintLessThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(anchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am proposing a fixed fork based on the JSQ latest `develop` branch commit.

It is using the `didMoveToWindow` solution. Not ideal but worth to try while waiting for Apple's answer about `inputAccessoryView`'s safe area layout guide attachment, or any other better fix.

You can add this to your Podfile, replacing the previous JSQ line:

```
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', :git => 'https://github.com/Tulleb/JSQMessagesViewController.git', :branch => 'develop', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

Answer (score 3):

**This answer is based on JSQMessagesViewController version 7.3.**

*Note: The code below contains some messy pragma directives to avoid compiler warnings. The code itself is actually quite simple once you see beyond the pragmas.*

This seems to solve the problem while still allowing the toolbar to be moved when the software keyboard is presented. I added the following code in my JSQMessagesViewController subclass:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [...]

    // To keep the toolbar inside the safe area on iPhone X, we need to install a new constraint that has higher priority than the one
    // JSQMessagesViewController manipulates when adjusting for the keyboard. The `toolbarBottomLayoutGuide` is a private property in our
    // superclass, so it's not straightforward to access it...
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"
        NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [self performSelector:@selector(toolbarBottomLayoutGuide)];
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
        constraint.priority = 999;
        [self.inputToolbar.bottomAnchor constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
}
```

**Edit:** For Swift users, the following trick should let you call the private objc method:

```
let constraint = perform(Selector(("toolbarBottomLayoutGuide"))).takeUnretainedValue() as! NSLayoutConstraint
constraint.priority = 999
```

**Edit:** The code that adjusts the contentInset of the collectionView is not called after this new constraint is added, so if the chat view contains more messages than fits the screen, the last message bubble is obscured by the input toolbar. I solved this by ensuring the insets are updated by adding the following code in <del>viewDidAppear</del> viewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"
[self performSelector:@selector(jsq_updateCollectionViewInsets)];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: I don't understand where do you get your `toolbarBottomLayoutGuide` from...

Comment: toolbarBottomLayoutGuide is defined in JSQMessagesViewController, which I'm subclassing. It's defined in the .m file so it's not visible to my implementation, which is why I'm using performSelector and adding the pragma directives.

Comment: I guess we're talking of different branches then. I am working on the latest `develop` commit from JSQ. [It looks like it has been removed since.](https://imgur.com/Cj8q6sk)

Comment: You're right, this solution is based on the 7.3 branch, I forgot about that. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

I m having same problem. I m trying to solve it by adding the JSQMessageViewController as a child view on a viewController that has safe area set up.

Being MyJSQMessageViewController a subclass of JSQMessagesViewController:

```
self.myJSQMessageViewController = [[MyJSQMessageViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:self.myJSQMessageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.myJSQMessageViewController.view];
[self.myJSQMessageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.myJSQMessageViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[ [self.myJSQMessageViewController.view.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor], [self.myJSQMessageViewController.view.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor], [self.myJSQMessageViewController.view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor], [self.myJSQMessageViewController.view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor] ]];
}
```

Not ideal solution but at least you will have input toolbar inside iOS11 safe area...
Bad news is that input toolbar wont be displayed on non safe areas so graphically wont be like a default toolbar (see image)

[image]

Comment: do your collectionView also being scrolled down a little bit when the input textview becomes the first responder?

Comment: No as far as I can notice. (of course I just tested on emulator) You can see small video on https://imgur.com/PqLx0Mq

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution without empty space below input toolbar on iPhoneX, the idea that not the whole toolbar `self` should be above the safe area, but only its `self.contentView`:

```
-(void) didMoveToWindow{
    [super didMoveToWindow];
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        if (self.window.safeAreaLayoutGuide != nil) {
            [[self.contentView bottomAnchor] constraintLessThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingBelowAnchor:self.window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor multiplier:1.0].active = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer.. to check self.window.safeAreaLayoutGuide is nil or not

Comment: if (self.window.safeAreaLayoutGuide != nil) {
            [[self bottomAnchor] constraintLessThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingBelowAnchor:self.window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor multiplier:1.0].active = YES;
        }

Comment: @HardikThakkar , another important thing here is setting bottomAnchor on `self.contentView` instead of `self` - toolbar would have extra space when keyboard is hidden, and won't when keyboard is shown

Answer (score 0):

Check this [response](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/2179#issuecomment-400932595):

Which state:

- Create an interface of `JSQMessagesInputToolbar` class, and
- Override `didMoveToWindow` method to add this code:

  ```
  - (void)didMoveToWindow {
      [super didMoveToWindow];
      NSLog(@"didMoveToWindow");
      if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {

          UILayoutGuide * _Nonnull safeArea = self.window.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
          if (safeArea) {
              NSLayoutYAxisAnchor * _Nonnull bottomAnchor = safeArea.bottomAnchor;
              [[self bottomAnchor] constraintLessThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingBelowAnchor:bottomAnchor multiplier:1.0].active = YES;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

**Note:** Creating interface is preferred over changing the class. Because if you used cocoa pods then each time you updated pods your changes will be overwritten.

I have checked it with iPhone XR (Simulator) and iPhone 7 (Device) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having issues with the toolbar even after applying the `didMoveToWindow` fix, it might be due to **IQKeyboardManager**.

With IQKeyboardManager I've experienced some problems when scrolling down (hiding keyboard) or tapping "intro", so it's better to have it disabled for that specific ViewController where the chat is. In that way, there won't be that undesired margin at the bottom.

[image: Bottom padding on JSQMessagesViewController toolbar]