# IOS 11 toolbar set as UITextView's inputView appears outside of safe area

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, ios11

I had made a UIToolbar to use as a custom input controller for a UITextView.  The code was as simple as:

```
_textView.inputView = myCustomToolbar;
[_textView reloadInputViews];
```

However in iOS 11 this custom toolbar appears below the safe area at the bottom of the screen.  Obviously Apple has a way around this, but I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly in this case.

Comment: How are you adding your custom toolbar into View are you using AutoLayout or are you adding it programmatically?

Comment: Programatically.  And I figured out how to fix.  This is a pre-exisitng issue.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282987/iphone-x-how-to-handle-view-controller-inputaccessoryview