# inputAccessoryView with intrinsicContentSize in iphone x not working

Tags: ios, swift4, iphone-x, inputaccessoryview

please do not down vote will try my best to explain problem.

i have an InputAccessoryView which was working fine before iphone x, in iphone x my inputAssesoryView is showing at very bottom below the layoutguide. i found following solution
[inputAccessoryView Iphone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282987/iphone-x-how-to-handle-view-controller-inputaccessoryview)

after following idea from above link i can place my textfield above the layout guid but it become unresponsive. which is happening because there is no frame size define for view of inputAccessoryView.

```
class ChatInputContainerView: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize.zero
    }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

lazy var inputTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = "Enter message..."
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.delegate = self
        return textField
    }()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight

    self.inputTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true

        self.inputTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.inputTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.inputTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive = true


}

}
```

following is controller where i am using inputAccessory View

```
class chatController: UITextFieldDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

lazy var inputContainerView: ChatInputContainerView = {
       // let chatInputContainerView = ChatInputContainerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))

        let chatInputContainerView = ChatInputContainerView()
        chatInputContainerView.chatLogController = self
        return chatInputContainerView
    }()

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        get {

           return inputContainerView
        }
    }

 override var canBecomeFirstResponder : Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

previously i was using following code to get size of InputAccessoryView which place the view at the bottom with fix height.

```
let chatInputContainerView = ChatInputContainerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
```

but now i am using following to set inputAccessoryView which is not working properly, textfield inside view become unresponsive because parent view have no size define.

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
            return CGSize.zero
        }
 autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
```

in following image you can see all my control are now above the safeAreaLayout but they become unresponsive.
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDmkv.png)

let me know if you do not understand. please help thank you in advance.

Comment: A bit late, tho you might want to check this: https://github.com/29satnam/InputAccessoryView

Comment: @SatnamSync its never late for right things. thank you for this repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a top anchor to your 'inputTextField'

```
self.inputTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
```

I might be wrong but without knowing where the top is the 'ChatInputContainerView' will have zero height.

Comment: it kind of work but the inputContainerView is Squeezed check this image  [link](https://ibb.co/jC6T8H). how do i increase size of the InputAccessoryView?

Comment: i tried to increase the font size of inputTextField but still the size of inputAccessoryView is same. thanx for the help @Landon

Comment: working fine problem is solved. the button was squeezed because i was using UIImageView and the contentMode Propery was not set thats why the plus icon was squeezed.