# iOS 11 extra space between keyboard and accessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, ios11, inputaccessoryview

I have some weird UI bug with `inputAccessoryView` and keyboard.
Code to add `inputAccessoryView` in `viewDidLoad`

```
        let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar()
    keyboardToolbar.items = [
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Hide", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(resignFirstResponder))
    ]

    keyboardToolbar.barStyle = barStyle
    keyboardToolbar.sizeToFit()

    myTextfield.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
```

First time entering screen and tap to textfield works good.
After closing this screen (popViewController) and entering it again and get focus to textField I've got this:
UIToolBar is above keyboard. Empty space have height = keyboard height

**ui bug image**
[image]

Comment: Try specifying the frame for your `UIToolBar`: `let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 40))`

Comment: Doesn't help. Also tried replace UIToolBar with custom UIView - same bug

Comment: have you implemented this function your self [resignFirstResponder]?

Answer (score 0):

this because there is safe area in IOS 11 and this space appear on iphone X

Check this post may be duplicated

[iPhone X how to handle View Controller inputAccessoryView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282987/iphone-x-how-to-handle-view-controller-inputaccessoryview)

Comment: Some different problem in my case because first time keyboard appears all look fine. And after a bug caused toolbar's button 'Hide' is located there it is supposed to be so I can tap on empty space above keyboard and Hide calls. Looks like just UI render problem

Comment: What code? I've tried layoutIfNeeded() and setNeedsDisplay(). Doesn't help

Comment: where you add this code in Viewdidload , previous code work with me without any error

Comment: I have many elements, few animation in screen's lifecycle and reactive (rxswift) on textField. So I'll guess this is not a common bug.

Comment: May be try it alone make sure it not constrained

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the reason but workaround is to call either

```
view.endEditing
```

or

```
textField.resignFirstResponder()
```

in

```
viewWillDisappear
```