# UITabBar Transition Issue Below iOS 11 Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I got this transition issue with iOS 9, I've attached a GIF below.

It looks like the custom `textView` is presuming x-axis of the tab bar top before segue and then settling to its original position.

However there's no issue with iOS 11, but same with iOS 10.

I also suspect this might be caused by the `push` segue, since it transitions fine with the other kinds of segue (without any height settling glitch).

I'm using Auto-layout. The comment `textView` is pinned to buttom of `superView`. Any tip would be highly appreciated.

Here's the code that's dismissing `UITabBar` on push.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "previewVC" {
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! PostViewController
        destinationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Here's a full-stack solution that worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46510833/4427884

Comment: A complete solution that I built: https://github.com/29satnam/InputAccessoryView

Answer (score 1):

Try another solution.

Use Your text as input accessory view of `UIViewController`  so remove that bottom view from storyboard

Add Following in your view controller

```
var viewAcc: UIView?
var sendButton: UIButton!
var inputTextField: UITextField!

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return viewAcc
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
```

In View Did load method add following code  
Note:Please change constraints according to your requirement

```
    viewAcc = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
    viewAcc?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    inputTextField = UITextField (frame: CGRect(x:8, y:0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44 ))
    inputTextField.inputAccessoryView = nil
    inputTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    inputTextField.placeholder = "Enter message..."
    viewAcc?.backgroundColor = .white
    viewAcc?.addSubview(inputTextField);

    let topBorderView = UIView()
    topBorderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
    viewAcc?.addSubview(topBorderView)
    viewAcc?.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: topBorderView)
    viewAcc?.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(0.5)]", views: topBorderView)

    sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    sendButton.isEnabled = true
    sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
    sendButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
    sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSend), for: .touchUpInside)
    viewAcc?.addSubview(sendButton)

    inputTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 7.5))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sendButton, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: -2))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -8))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -4.5))
```

As your text view is not subview of view controller so it will work as expected

**EDIT IPHONE X SUPPORT**

```
lazy var viewAcc: SafeAreaInputAccessoryViewWrapperView = {
    return SafeAreaInputAccessoryViewWrapperView(for: button)
}()
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: This can't be the solution. 
However that comment view is sub class of https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView
Removing that from `storyboard` will destroy the whole setup.

Comment: @SatnamSync You can create That textview programmatically as well

Comment: Of course it can be created. And there’s not much difference between both approaches. If you could mention what be the solution precisely, would be much appreciated.

Comment: @SatnamSync then you just need to use  Growing Textview object at the  place of inputTextField

Comment: Do you have a similar implementation of the same? Can you share the code please.

Comment: @SatnamSync yes I did for comment screen and  it is the same code i have used please let me know difficulties you are facing

Comment: @SatnamSync You just need to follow the steps as per answer it is easy to do :)

Comment: Wow! It does work. Do you have a fix for the iPhone X safe area? It's little under the accessible region.

Comment: @SatnamSync Glad that solution worked , Sorry brother i didn't checked in iphone X

Comment: Not a problem! I will look for one and update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SatnamSync Great !! , Good luck

Comment: @SatnamSync Above the textfield are you using tableview or collection view ? that graph ? in image

Comment: It’s a tableView in a `UIViewController`.

Comment: @SatnamSync Great , Now try this trick , Go to storyboard select tableview on right panel change keyboard dismiss mode to interactive. Now You are able to dismiss keyboard with just swiping down just like APPLE does in default messages app. Let me know if any difficulties

Comment: @SatnamSync see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282987/iphone-x-how-to-handle-view-controller-inputaccessoryview

Comment: @SatnamSync Bro Why did you remove upvote and accepted answer ?

Comment: Sorry for that but it's still not a full stack answer and has issues when used with a `UITableView`. And using a 3rd party library doesn't count as a robust solution. How bout you try it once and then post it? Thanks for help. <3

Comment: @SatnamSync No worries ,  Hope that you find better answer that solve your problem :)

Comment: I built a complete solution you might want to check it out https://github.com/29satnam/InputAccessoryView