# moving View up with textfield and Button when keyboard appear Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I know there are a few posted questions on this topic, but none of them worked. I have a tableview and under it there's a UIView that contains a textfield and button. When my keyboard appears, it covers the whole UIView, making me unable to click "Send". The image to show how my app looks like :

[image]

at the moment, my codes are:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    inputTextField.delegate = self
    inputTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    inputTextField.clipsToBounds = true
    sendButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    sendButton.clipsToBounds = true
    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
    loadMsg()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    inputTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

How should I move the UIView up along with the textfield and button that is contained by the UIView when my keyboard appears?

Comment: You should use inputAccessoryView, please find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689528/add-a-view-on-top-of-the-keyboard-using-inputaccessoryview-swift)

Comment: Are you use `AutoLayout` to layout your views

Comment: yes I am @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: ok, i am looking into it now, @PPL

Comment: However you solved your problem but If you need keyboard dismiss just like apple native messages app (drag down to dismiss) then you should implement this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293919/uitabbar-transition-issue-below-ios-11-swift/50294205#50294205

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is solution, Create bottom layout constraint reference of send button view

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var sendbuttonView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func handleKeyboardNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

        let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue

        let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow

        bottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardFrame!.height : 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

[Demo example](https://github.com/paresh1994/KeyboardEx)

Comment: can I know where is the login menu connected to??

Comment: is it the UIView?

Comment: NICE ONE!IT WORKED!

Answer (score 6):

Just add [this](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) library into your project using POD and thats it. It will automatically do it. You have not to do anything else.

Add pod like that

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

In AppDelegate.swift, just import IQKeyboardManagerSwift framework and enable IQKeyboardManager.

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

  IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

  return true
 }
}
```

For reference please have a look on this url, https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19720757)

Comment: @mag_zbc please check now.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2**

in viewDidLoad()

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboard(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboard(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboard(notification:)), name:UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

and Method

```
@objc func keyboard(notification:Notification) {
        guard let keyboardReact = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else{
            return
        }

        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification ||  notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardReact.height
        }else{
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
//Declare a delegate, assign your textField to the delegate and then include these methods

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    return YES;
}


- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Assign new frame to your view 
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-110,320,460)]; //here taken -110 for example i.e. your view will be scrolled to -110. change its value according to your requirement.

}

-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by move View up with `constraint`  here `actionBarPaddingBottomConstranit`  is Constraint connect to your Input View `Bottom` constraint Check image

[image]

**In ViewDidload :**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         self.keybordControl()
    }
```

**Extension :**

```
extension ViewController{

    func keybordControl(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    }


    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        self.keyboardControl(notification, isShowing: true)
    }



    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
        self.keyboardControl(notification, isShowing: false)
    }



     private func keyboardControl(_ notification: Notification, isShowing: Bool) {

        /* Handle the Keyboard property of Default, Text*/

        var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue
        let curve = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).uint32Value

        let convertedFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardRect!, from: nil)
        let heightOffset = self.view.bounds.size.height - convertedFrame.origin.y
        let options = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(curve!) << 16 | UIViewAnimationOptions.beginFromCurrentState.rawValue)
        let duration = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).doubleValue


        var  pureheightOffset : CGFloat = -heightOffset

        if isShowing {
           if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
               pureheightOffset = pureheightOffset + view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
            }
        }
        self.actionBarPaddingBottomConstranit?.update(offset:pureheightOffset)

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: duration!,
            delay: 0,
            options: options,
            animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        },
            completion: { bool in

        })

    }
}
```

Comment: TQ so much for the help!

Comment: your answer is good, shall i use this code `extension UIViewController` instead of `extension ViewController`

Comment: Yes Check Updated Answer

Answer (score 0):

Call below method in ViewDidLoad:

```
func keyboardSettings(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))))
        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self.view , action : #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
        swipeDown.direction = .down
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
    }
```

Then add below method for keyboard configuration:

```
@objc func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue{
                if let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue{

                    let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
                    let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
                    let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

                    if (endFrame.origin.y) >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
                        self.const_ViewMessage_Bottom?.constant = 0.0
                    } else {
                        self.const_ViewMessage_Bottom?.constant = endFrame.size.height
                    }

                    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                                   delay: TimeInterval(0),
                                   options: animationCurve,
                                   animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                                   completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`self.const_ViewMessage_Bottom` is bottom constraint of UIView with textfield.

Answer (score 0):

with one extension to use in all ViewControllers. Create a empty swift file copy this code inside file

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {

    func keyboardCheck() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }

}
```

Then call the function inside ViewDidLoad   Usage:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       self.keyboardCheck()
    }
```