# Unable to make View up when tapping on textfield in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, keyboard

I have textfield and button inside containerview, now if i tap on textfield i need containerview has to up with keyboard

according to  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325019/moving-view-up-with-textfield-and-button-when-keyboard-appear-swift)

for bottom view

```
bottom = leading = trailing = 0, height = 80
```

and

```
i have created containerview bottom constraint to NSLayoutConstraint
```

and addd code like this: but i am unable to move container viewup, only keyboard coming.. view not comingup, where am i wrong

```
 class MessageDetailsVCViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var messageTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var viewbottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomContainerView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.bottomContainerView.superview?.setNeedsLayout()
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
         textField.resignFirstResponder()
         return true
     }
 
 override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
     return true
 }
@objc func handleKeyboardNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        
        let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue
        
        let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification
        
        viewbottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardFrame!.height : 0
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}

}
```

Comment: @Pancho, same, view not coming up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try positive `keyboardFrame!.height`

```
viewbottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? keyboardFrame!.height : 0
```

Comment: but i am getting small gap between viewbottomConstraint and keyboard in iphone 12